# Returning a promise from within a deferred's callback

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-deferred

I am working on some anync stuff and I really want to implement that in a good manner.

Consider following code

```
function getData(latency) {
    var deferred = $.Deferred();

    window.setTimeout(function () {
        deferred.resolve(Math.random());
    }, latency + 100);

    return deferred.promise();
}
function getSpecialData() {
    var deferreds = [];
    for (var i = 0; i < 3; i++) {
        deferreds.push(getData(1000 * i));
    }
    return $.when.apply($, deferreds);
}

function log(msg) {
    $("#console").append("<li>" + msg + "</li>");
    console.log(msg);
}

getData(3000)
.done(function () {
    log("got 3000 data");
    return getSpecialData()
    .done(function () {
        log("got special data");
    });
})
.always(function () {
    log("got all data");
});
```

As you can see, I am returning a promise from within both getData and getSpecialData functions. I am also chaining calls to these functions the way you see. What is more, I am returning a promise from within the getData done callback.

I have been expecting that the deferred object cares about what its callbacks return and if it's a promise, wait for that promise to resolve and then another callback. What is actually happening is that it doesn't care about what I am returning from within the callback. The order is:

1. Call getData, after 3s get the `"got 3000 data"` info,
2. at the same time fire getSpecialData and the `always` callback with `"got all data"` message

What I want to achieve is the following order of function calls:

1. Call getData, after 3s get the `"got 3000 data"` information,
2. call getSpecialData, after 3s get the `"got special data"` information,
3. immediately after `"got all data"` message.

What is the best approach to make it work the way I want?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That's exactly what `.then()` (or `.pipe()` before jQuery 1.8) does.

Call that instead of `.done()`.

Comment: Well, you are right. I must have misunderstood the difference between these two. With `.then()` it seems to work great. However it also seems to be necessary to return that inner promise, so I do. Thank you

Answer (score 0):

You cannot `return` anything from a callback, because that's meaningless - the result is not used anywhere in the caller, it's type is effectively `void`.

To chain actions, you can use [`then`](http://api.jquery.com/deferred.then/) instead of `done`. The method will return a promise for the (async) result of the callback, which can itself be a promise.